# How many ways to paint a board with 2 colors..

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

You got a fence, you need to paint the boards with black and white, but can not have 3 or more boards same color in a row. how many ways do you have?

Comment: "roll" was a typo, i meant row.

Answer (score 1):

As user bof pointed out in a comment, the OP is most likely looking for the number of binary strings avoiding the substrings $000$ and $111$.  If so, then the answer can be found in sequence [A128588](http://oeis.org/A128588) of the OEIS, where $a(n)$ is the number of binary strings of length $n-1$ avoiding the substrings $000$ and $111$.  The sequence starts "$1, 2, 4, 6, 10, 16, 26, 42,\ldots$," so, for example, if there are $3$ boards, there are $a(4)=6$ ways of painting the board: $001,010,011,100,101,110$.

Comment: Your answer doesn't have much to do with the OP's question, does it? Maybe a reference to [A128588](http://oeis.org/A128588) in the OEIS would be more helpful.

Comment: @bof, it would depend on what the OP really wants.  If the OP wants to avoid only $000$ and $111$, then your comment answers the question.  If you add it as an answer, I will upvote it.

Comment: The number of total boards is > 3 , or more like infinite